# The type of the data argument in requests

Tags: python, json, curl, python-requests

Consider (taken from [this doc](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/platforms/get-started/#curl)):

```
curl -v POST https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token \
  -H "Accept: application/json" \
  -H "Accept-Language: en_US" \
  -u "CLIENT_ID:SECRET" \
  -d "grant_type=client_credentials"
```

Here the equal sign is used in `-d`. [Curl converter](https://curlconverter.com) translates this into Python as follows:

```
import requests

headers = {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Accept-Language': 'en_US',
}

data = {
  'grant_type': 'client_credentials'
}

response = requests.post('https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token', headers=headers, data=data, auth=('CLIENT_ID', 'SECRET'))
```

Note that `data` is a dictionary.

On the other hand, consider (taken from [this doc](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/server-side-api-calls/create-order/)):

```
curl -v -X POST https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-H "Authorization: Bearer Access-Token" \
-d '{
  "intent": "CAPTURE",
  "purchase_units": [
    {
      "amount": {
        "currency_code": "USD",
        "value": "100.00"
      }
    }
  ]
}'
```

[Curl converter](https://curlconverter.com) translates this into Python as follows:

```
import requests

headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'Bearer Access-Token',
}

data = '{\n  "intent": "CAPTURE",\n  "purchase_units": [\n    {\n      "amount": {\n        "currency_code": "USD",\n        "value": "100.00"\n      }\n    }\n  ]\n}'

response = requests.post('https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders', headers=headers, data=data)
```

In this case, `data` is a string.

I ran both Python codes and they are indeed correct. Furthermore, in the first example, if I stringify the dictionary, it would not work. Similarly, in the second example, if I try to use a dictionary just like in the first one, it would not work.

Why is `data` of different types in these two examples (the Python version)? When is it supposed to be a dictionary and when is it supposed to be a string? How is the equal sign different from colon in Curl?

Comment: I think curl converter must be wrong. In the second example, `data` should be a dictionary object in my opnion. As far I'm aware, requests does stringify the `data` object when making the rquest to the API.

Comment: Post encodes dictionaries passed as `data` to _form data_ by default: https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests. For JSON you pass the dictionary as `json` or, as your example does, stringify it first.

Comment: @rv.kvetch As I wrote in the question, the version produced by the converter worked, while a version with a dictionary did not.

Comment: @jonrsharpe As I wrote in the question, the first example worked only as a dictionary, while the second only as a string...

Comment: Yes, I understand that. The link above explains why. If you stringify the dictionary to _JSON_ in the first example, you're no longer sending _form data_, so it shouldn't be surprising that it doesn't work - at minimum, if the server accepts it, you'd need to set the Content-Type header accordingly (as the second example does). data can be a dictionary if you want to send form data, because that's what it's serialised to - if you want to send anything else, including JSON, you need to serialise it to a string yourself (you could also serialise to form data yourself, but why bother).

Comment: And a colon and equals sign _aren't_ different to curl, at least not in the `-d`/`--data` - it's just a string, it could represent form data (the default Content-Type header curl sets), JSON, or something else entirely.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I have now looked up the link and am confused about the term *form-encoded*. In particular, in their examples, how is `payload = {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'}` more form-encoded than `payload = {'some': 'data'}`?

Comment: They're both _dictionaries_, not serialised/encoded at all. You need to look at what's in the actual _request_ (what was in your original curl commands) - `'some=data'` (form data, created by requests, but you could just do `data='some=data'` if you wanted to) vs. `'{"some": "data"}'` (JSON - notice they're using `json.dumps` to create that string). You could switch the dictionaries between the two examples, their specific content doesn't matter.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Do you see why it makes sense to use different methods for the two examples from PayPal API in the question?

Comment: It's entirely up to them what their API accepts, their docs should tell you. Maybe it takes whichever you send according to the headers, I don't know.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thank you very much. All this help in the comments, while you could have easily gotten an accepted reply for it. Impressed by your altruistic willingness to help. (Nonetheless, I will gladly accept a reply if you submit it)